# Can I create a master spreadsheet of data and then only allow each individual to see their row?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have compile data for our first aid squad for a program that we have.
Each person earns points for various activities.

I have a master spreadsheet which I share with the group. However, I want people to be able to ONLY see their row. Is there a way to do this?

Thoughts I had and am not sure if this is possible
Is there was a way to create a doc for each person for their row to filter to?
Or have a master sheet and each person have their own individual sheet that I can share the link to each person. Like a pivot table maybe? From one sheet to another.

It all centers on one person being competitive and annoying so I wanted to individualize the data so each person only sees their totals.

THANK YOU for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

The [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) formula allows you to insert a specific range of cells from one spreadsheet to another. Thus, you can have a master spreadsheet with all the data and a *user-specific* spreadsheet that includes only the relevant portion of master data. Share the user-specific spreadsheet with the appropriate person. They can view the data in their spreadsheet, not the master spreadsheet.

[image]